# issue with piping find into sed (find and replace)

Tags: bash, sed

Here is my current code, my goal is to find every file in a given directory (recursively) and replace "FIND" with "REPLACEWITH" and overwrite the files.

```
FIND='ALEX'
REPLACEWITH='<strong>ALEX</strong>'

DIRECTORY='/some/directory/'

find $DIRECTORY -type f -name "*.html" -print0  |
 LANG=C xargs -0  sed  -i "s|$FIND|$REPLACEWITH|g"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
sed: 1: "/some/directory ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Comment: I was using one "safe" file to test my script, I changed it in the above code to look for any .html files

Comment: BashFAQ #21 covers (in great detail!) doing find/replace over a directory structure: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021

Comment: ...we also have a lot (a very large lot) of questions and answers on doing so properly in the knowledge base. Is there a reason to ask a new question, rather than to use one of the confirmed-correct answers from those?

Comment: Note that your anonymization has had a bizarre effect, in that the `command a` in your question no longer refers to any part of the command you've posted here.

Comment: ...and as an aside for the future, you shouldn't use all-caps names for your own variables; those are reserved for shell-provided and system variables (per convention described in the environment variable docs in IEEE Std 1003.1 -- see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables use the same namespace).

Comment: Anyhow, using `awk` instead of `sed` in the manner suggested by BashFAQ #21 will completely moot any issues with your find/replace text being parsed as sed script rather than data, which is where your issue here originates.

Comment: (and as @ruakh says -- do test, when anonymizing something, that your modified code still produces the same bug as the original did; otherwise, it's not of much use to us).

Comment: ...I wonder if, perhaps, there might be newlines or semicolons in either the source or destination strings?

Comment: I think you just forgot to set the replace-str in xargs and provide the match: find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | LANG=C xargs -I {} -0 sed -i "s|${FIND}|${REPLACEWITH}|g" {}

Comment: @A.Danischewski, the OP's original code already uses double quotes for the expansion, so it already is expanding the strings into the sed script. As for `-I {}`, that's making `xargs` only pass one filename per invocation, which makes things unnecessarily inefficient, but doesn't otherwise change semantics at all. Unless either find or replace strings include `{}` as a substring, in which case it would substitute the filename into them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#Files), you can use `perl` to perform search-and-replace operations with no potential for data being treated as code:

```
in="$FIND" out="$REPLACEWITH" find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -name '*.html' \
  -exec perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' '{}' +
```

If you want to include only files matching the FIND string, `find` can be told to only pass files which `grep` flags on to `perl`:

```
in="$FIND" out="$REPLACEWITH" find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -name '*.html' \
  -exec grep -F -q -e "$FIND" '{}' ';' \
  -exec perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' '{}' +
```

Because `grep` is being used to evaluate individual files, it's necessary to use one `grep` call per file so its exit status can be evaluated on a per-file basis; thus, the use of the less efficient `-exec ... {} ';'` action. For `perl`, it's possible to put multiple files to process on one command, hence the use of `-exec ... {} +`.

Note that `fgrep` is line-oriented; if your `FIND` string contains multiple lines, then files with any one of those lines will be passed to `perl` for replacements.

Comment: This seems to work really well, is there any way to make it replace multi-line code blocks?

Comment: One option (albeit rather inefficient) would be to use built-in string replacement support in bash. That is, something like: `content=$(<"$filename"); new_content=${content//$FIND/$REPLACEWITH}; if [[ $content != "$content" ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$content" >"$filename"`

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question, if you can't find any directly on-point. And if you do, feel free to link me in. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have `find` invoke `sed` directly although I think all the modification times on your files will be affected (which might matter or not):

```
find $DIRECTORY -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -i "s|$FIND|$REPLACEWITH|g" '{}' ';'
```

Comment: oh, that's bad, is there a way to only modify the files if they contain the string in FIND?

Comment: I'm not sure how invoking `sed` directly from `find` would help -- the issue is clearly `sed` treating part of the `FIND` or `REPLACE` strings as sed script rather than data.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: in a general case, yes, that's always a concern

Comment: @glasses : I think `sed -i` always affects the modification time. I think you would need a smarter script to control for that

Comment: @Luis, I'm not just worried about in "the general case", but given the error the OP posted -- `command a expects \ followed by text` -- there's clearly input to `sed` being viewed as such a command. No, the code they gave here doesn't generate it, but that's a matter of bad anonymization.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy FYI I didn't try the original command, but I did test the one in my answer in a script similar to the OP's, on the environment I have: the MSYS git bash on Windows

Comment: Sure -- and your command will work fine given the data the OP posted in their question, but -- the thing is -- *the command they posted in their question will also work fine with that data*. Their **real** data, producing the bug, is something they haven't shown us at all.

Comment: Just grep it first: `find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -name "*.html" -exec bash -c "grep -q \"${FIND}\" {} && sed -i \"s|${FIND}|${REPLACEWITH}|g\" {}" \;`

Comment: @A.Danischewski, you don't need to exec bash for that; the version I already had in my answer, with two `-exec`s on a single `find` command (the first calling `grep`), has the same resulting behavior: An `-exec` is not only an action, but also a filter; if it returns false, then subsequent actions aren't called.

Comment: @Charles Yea, you can remove a little bit of context overhead with: `find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep -q "${FIND}" {} \; -exec sed -i "s|${FIND}|${REPLACEWITH}|g" {} +`

Comment: @A.Danischewski, indeed. However, that does little to help the OP here, where their actual text being found and replaced (as opposed to the code and data they gave in their question, which doesn't reproduce the error they report) includes an "a" in a context where it's treated as a sed command.

Comment: @Charles He probably needs to choose an appropriate delimiter, SOH $'\001' would probably do. Not every system has perl and the OP question tags are Bash and Sed (not Perl). If he needs to make it robust he can sweep the text for the delimiter starting w/001 SOH and if its present in the text start looping over the unprintables in ascii until  he finds one that isn't present. An example is here: https://github.com/AdamDanischewski/r-n-f-bash-rename-script/blob/master/ren_file.bsh (see line 111).

Comment: @A.Danischewski, `sed` and `awk` are no more a part of bash than `perl` is -- though they certainly do get points for being POSIX-specified, and I'm happy to note that BashFAQ #21 includes an `awk` solution which completely avoids potential for escapes from data to code just as the `perl` solution, *given in that same FAQ*, which I adopted for my answer does. And the immediate cause of the escape could indeed be a poor choice of delimiter -- but but it also could be newlines, which merely selecting another delimiter wouldn't solve.

Comment: ...if we wanted a *pure* bash solution, it'd be something like `new_content=${content//$FIND/$REPLACEWITH}`. But, as someone who's been around this tag for a while with a penchant for creating pure-bash solutions when they're feasible, I can assert with some confidence that folks tend to care a great deal more about practicality than purity.